# Error during REST call from code while with Postman with the same config everything is OK

Tags: rest, spring-boot

recently I've faced the problem of different behavior whenever I make a call through the Postman and programmatically with the same config.
During call from code I receive 400 bad request and my debugging showed no explicit issues.

Here is I'm doing from postman:
I make a call to https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1.3/live_streams/{streamId}/start
with presseted headers wsc-api-key and wsc-access-key and method type PUT
and everything is going smoothly.

What I'm doing in code :

I've set up a HttpEntity with headers and json content type

```
@Bean
    public HttpEntity<String> httpEntity() {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON));
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.add("wsc-api-key", wscApiKey);
        headers.add("wsc-access-key", wscAccessKey);
        return new HttpEntity<>("parameters", headers);
    }
```

created a simple method with PUT http method type

```
public Optional<LiveStreamWrapper> startStream(String streamId) {
        String wowzaCloudStreamEndpoint = wowzaCloudUrl + "/" + streamId + "/start";
        logger.info("Wowza endpoint :" + wowzaCloudStreamEndpoint);
        ResponseEntity<LiveStreamWrapper> liveStreamWrapperResponseEntity = restTemplate.exchange(wowzaCloudStreamEndpoint, HttpMethod.PUT, entity, LiveStreamWrapper.class);
        return Optional.ofNullable(liveStreamWrapperResponseEntity.getBody());
    }
```

And here I'm receiving 400 bad request even with everything being the same. I'm cracking y head over this for quite some time, can somebody please give a hint?

UPD:
postman request

```
{
            "name": "stream start",
            "request": {
                "method": "PUT",
                "header": [
                    {
                        "key": "Content-Type",
                        "name": "Content-Type",
                        "value": "application/json",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "wsc-api-key",
                        "value": "{{wsc-api-key}}",
                        "type": "text"
                    },
                    {
                        "key": "wsc-access-key",
                        "value": "{{wsc-access-key}}",
                        "type": "text"
                    }
                ],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": ""
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1.3/live_streams/pt4v2pf1/start",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "api",
                        "cloud",
                        "wowza",
                        "com"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "v1.3",
                        "live_streams",
                        "pt4v2pf1",
                        "start"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        },
```

UPD:
after I've followed the @Isank advice behaviour changed to HttpClientErrorException$UnprocessableEntity: 422 Unprocessable Entity

Now HttpEntity config looks like this

```
@Bean
    public HttpEntity<String> httpEntity() {
        MultiValueMap<String, String> headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        headers.set("wsc-api-key", wscApiKey);
        headers.set("wsc-access-key", wscAccessKey);
        return new HttpEntity<>(headers);
    }
```

UPD:
I've resolved all my issues thank you everyone!
In order to solve Unprocessable entity I've followed suggestions from that tread:
[RestTemplate--> Exchange produces: 422 Unprocessable Entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455972/resttemplate-exchange-produces-422-unprocessable-entity)
Happy coding!

Comment: can you plz add the postman request for comparison?

Comment: @miklosh, you're actually using `public HttpEntity(@Nullable T body, @Nullable MultiValueMap<String, String> headers)` variant. So, `parameters` string itself is becoming a part of your request body which might be resulting in the bad request error. I think what you actually need is `public HttpEntity(MultiValueMap<String, String> headers)`

Comment: @TommyBrettschneider here : https://api.cloud.wowza.com/api/v1.3/live_streams/pt4v2pf1/start

Comment: @Miklosh that's the url you're calling. I meant your Postman request details - I believe you can export it...